# How did 'module' end up as synonym for the '7' tag?

Tags: support, tags

I figured the term `extension` as used in Drupal 8 does not exist here yet. So I felt it would make sense to map it as a synonym for [module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module).

Surprisingly I noticed that [module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) was already mapped as synonym for [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7)... Arguably [module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) would not be a very good tag, as it very vague when it should be used. But wouldn't it make more sense to delete it rather than remapping it to D7?

Or was this to prevent others from re-creating it after deletion and was this the 'safest' method?

Comment: It was merged after removing it from questions not about Drupal 7. It should not have been marked as synonym.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks for explaining and correcting it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I just noticed that `module` is now a synonym for `8`. Is this again a mistake?

Comment: I temporarly set it as synonym to stop users using it again.

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) was merged with [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7) after removing it from questions not about Drupal 7. It should not have been marked as synonym. The UI allowing to merge tags has a checkbox to make the merged tag a synonym of the other tag, and it was checked by mistake.

I removed [module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) from the synonyms of [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7).